# Emacs can't load swi-prolog with default prolog-mode?

Tags: emacs, prolog, swi-prolog, emacs24

My Gnu Emacs 24.4 on Win 8 can't seem to work with it's default prolog mode. I have the latest version of SWI Prolog.

When I load Gnu Emacs and type in Mx prolog-mode, the syntax gets highlighted. However, I am not able to compile the rules, or do anything with them. When I try to run prolog from inside Emacs using Cc RET, it says "Searching for program: no such file or directory, prolog".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message tells you that Emacs couldn't find any executable with name `prolog` in `load-path`.  So presumably the problem is that you haven't put your installation of SWI-Prolog into your `$PATH`.

An alternative to setting $PATH in your environment (or `load-path` in your `~/.emacs`) is to set `prolog-program-name` in your `~/.emacs`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you please write the command for that as well. I'm an Emacs newbie, so I don't know how to make it work.

I tried Google, but there seems to be no support for the default prolog mode.

My prolog path is:
C:\Program Files (x86)\swipl\bin\swipl-win.exe

Comment: I don't use Windows so I don't know how to change the $PATH there.  But it's not specific to Emacs, nor to SWI-Prolog, so there should be plenty of info on the web about that.  If you want to do it within Emacs, then `(setq prolog-program-name "C:/Program Files (x86)/swipl/bin/swipl-win.exe")` should do it.

Answer (score -2):

You wouldn't happen to be taking cmsc330 would you? Anyway if your not wedded to Emacs, Eclipse has a plugin for SWI and it autofills as well. I would just use eclipse.

Comment: Thanks for the information about Eclipse. But, I've grown too fond of Emacs to give up now :)...